# remove elements from a list based on condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I've a sample dataframe `df`

```
id    joined_day      joined_month     current_month      dates
1        15                9                 9            [16, 17, 18]
2        12                9                 9            [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 23]
3        9                 9                 9            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9]
4        10                9                 9            []
```

How can I remove the elements from the `list` of the `dates` column if `df['joined_month'] == df['current_month']` and whatever the elements in the list are less than the `joined_day`?

Desired result

```
id       day     joined_month      current_month          dates
1        15           9                   9              [16, 17, 18]
2        12           9                   9              [12, 23]
3        9            9                   9              [9]
4        10           9                   9              []
```

considering `id`=2, in [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 23] with `day` 12, there are [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] that are less than 12 and the elements are removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
mask = df.joined_month.eq(df.current_month)
df.loc[mask, "dates"] = df[mask].apply(
    lambda x: [v for v in x["dates"] if v >= x.joined_day], axis=1
)

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id  joined_day  joined_month  current_month         dates
0   1          15             9              9  [16, 17, 18]
1   2          12             9              9      [12, 23]
2   3           9             9              9           [9]
3   4          10             9              9            []
```

Comment: If I need to, how can I apply multiple masks? example, one more condition like `df['current_year']==df['joining_month']`?

Comment: @aristotle11 Yes of course, you can combine the masks with logical AND/OR (`&` or `|`)